# Public user and Admin differentiation for just viewing and making changes

Tags: php, laravel

I need make a site and in that site public users can directly see the dashboard/homepage, about page, contact page but can't add or edit or delete posts. These previlages is given only to admin user. They need to log in and then they can add content and modify it. I am making this project in laravel.   thanks in advance

Comment: Thats a good start for a project outline. What exactly is your question though?

Comment: @Darren : For example I have a site and when any guests puts that url in browsers then welcome page comes right, then the guests simply views the content but cannot edit or delete. But we can login the admins from the database and after login admin have all the privileges for editing, adding content, deleting and so on.
Please help me 
Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a home page with route outside of auth-middleware
and for admin page(login only) just put `->middleware('auth');` in the end of your route

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

or you can just put a group route

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@Index'); //url == http://www.example.com
Route::get('/contact', 'IndexController@Contact'); //url == http://www.example.com/contact
Route::auth(); //default laravel auth route like login, register, reset pass (make sure to disable register controller in app/Http/Controllers/Auth)
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web'], 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () { 
    //your route for authentication only 
    Route::get('/admin/edit/', 'AdminController@Edit'); //url == http://www.example.com/admin/edit/
    Route::get('/admin/list/', 'AdminController@List'); //url == http://www.example.com/admin/list/
});
```

Comment: Yes I got it but doing so can we get the edited content by admins for homepage also? It need to be published to the public homepage after admins adds or modifies the content of the home page.
The homepage can only be viewed by guests but the same home page is modified by admins and the changed content should be again viewed by guests

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider building your privileges using the Laravel `Authorization` functionality.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Using the `Gates` and `Policies` you can only allow certain actions to be taken if that user has the correct policy assigned to them.

How you assign the policy a user is up to you but i would either suggest a basic `is_admin` boolean on your `User` table or create some sort of `user_roles` table.